# ColorBox - auto pop-up (how to?)

Tags: jquery-plugins, colorbox

Is there anyway to make ColorBox (jquery popup script) actually 'pop-up' automatically, and if so, what part do i edit for that?
I need it popped up after about 3 seconds on home page.
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Set the **open** parameter to true. (It defaults to false); if want a delay you'll have write a bit of javascript with an interval.

Answer (score 1):

You can set open property to **true**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //For url
        $.fn.colorbox({href:"example.html", open:true});

        //For link
        $("a.example").colorbox({open:true});

        //For delay
        setTimeout("$.fn.colorbox({href:'example.html', width:500, height: 300,
        open:true});", 3000);

        //For inline
        $.fn.colorbox({inline:true, width: 660, height: 405, href:"#example"});
});
</script>
```

Here is the documentation: [jacklmoore.com/colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)